# Lost data after pg_ctl -m immediate

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I use PostgreSQL 9.6 after killing by mistake one of pid of postgres connections, my server shutdown totally.

I have almost 1T of data, so for restarting it takes a long time for speedy the restart I used: `pg_ctl -m i`

But this time I can't find my data in database, all sequences are incremented with the last value before restarting. The size of data is correct not initialised so, it's like that's my data is hidden.

As you can see in this picture:

[image: Size of postgres data directory]

No error found in the logs.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see a question here. I see lots of statements of what you have done.

Comment: Hi! Is visible the database with postgres user? If not perhaps this link can help you... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12350/postgresql-recovery-after-reboot

Comment: @Dragonthoughts ,

Comment: @Dragonthoughts , tnx for your replay , as you can see the size of directory data is almost 1T , but when i connect to the postgres and showing the data saved by des select , i can't see all just the data after restarting the server , like that's other data is hidden; for example whene i tape this request ** ` SELECT * FROM mytable WHETE mydate < the_date of crache ` ** the result is 0